# Query free booking based on time window and duration from MONGODB

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, nosql

I have the following problem for which I am looking for a solution.

I have a table in my database with the following structure:

| id | Date | 07:00 | 07:30 | 08:00 | 08:30 | 09:00 | 09:30 | 10:00 | 10:30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2022-02-02 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Now I get three parameters through a form by the user:

1. a date (here e.g. 2022-02-01)
2. a time window (here: e.g. 08:00am -10:30am)
3. a required duration (here: e.g. 1 hour)

Now I want to check whether an entry in the table where the date is 2022-02-01 has at least three consecutive 0s (three 0s = 1 hour) in the period 08:00-10:30. If so, the SELECT should return this entry and otherwise not.

Does anyone have an idea how I would write this SELECT for a MongoDB?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions! :)

Comment: How does the data look like? Why did you tag mysql and sql?

Comment: Perhaps write it in SQL, then use a guide like this to convert it to the correct syntax? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_query_document.htm

Comment: @FlexYourData, such conversions may work for **very** simple queries. Here I don't think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It heavily depends how this data is stored. Let's assume your data looks like this:

```
db.collection.insertOne({
   bookingTimes: [
      { t: ISODate('2022-02-01T07:00'), booked: false },
      { t: ISODate('2022-02-01T07:30'), booked: true },
      { t: ISODate('2022-02-01T08:00'), booked: false },
      { t: ISODate('2022-02-01T08:30'), booked: false },
      { t: ISODate('2022-02-01T09:00'), booked: false },
      { t: ISODate('2022-02-01T09:30'), booked: true },
      { t: ISODate('2022-02-01T10:00'), booked: false },
      { t: ISODate('2022-02-01T10:30'), booked: false },
   ]
})
```

Then a solution could be this one:

```
const requiredDuration = 60
db.collection.aggregate([
   // Filter window period
   {
      $set: {
         bookingTimes: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$bookingTimes",
               cond: {
                  $and: [
                     { $gte: ["$$this.t", ISODate('2022-02-01T08:00:00')] },
                     { $lte: ["$$this.t", ISODate('2022-02-01T10:30:00')] }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   // Sum up free Minutes
   {
      $set: {
         bookingTimes: {
            $reduce: {
               input: "$bookingTimes",
               initialValue: [],
               in: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                     "$$value", [{
                        $mergeObjects: [
                           "$$this",
                           {
                              minutes: {
                                 $cond: {
                                    if: "$$this.booked",
                                    then: 0,
                                    else: { $add: [{ $ifNull: [{ $last: "$$value.minutes" }, 0] }, 30] }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }]
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   // Get periods longer than 60 Minutes
   {
      $set: {
         bookingTimes: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$bookingTimes",
               cond: { $gt: ["$$this.minutes", requiredDuration] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   // Some cosmetic for output
   {
      $set: {
         freeTimes: {
            $map: {
               input: "$bookingTimes", in: {
                  start: {
                     $dateSubtract: {
                        startDate: "$$this.t",
                        unit: "minute",
                        amount: requiredDuration,
                     }
                  }, end: "$$this.t"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```